# How do I prevent the anchor tag from overwriting my CSS style

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles, anchor

I'm very new to all this. I'm trying to make my image into a link using the anchor tag but doing so seems to ignore the previous style I had for the image and I'm not sure why. In short: why does adding this element change the whole style?

.slider keeps all the images in line and the same size while .slider>img keeps the round shape of each img. For some reason I think adding the anchor element ruins the .slider>img style.

Is there a way I can keep the layout of everything the same while allowing the image to contain a link?

```css
 /* Element */
    *, *::after, *::before{
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
 
    /* Variable */
    :root{
         --handle-size: 3rem;
         --img-gap: .25rem;
    }


    .body{
       margin: 0;
    }

    .container{
       display: flex;
       justify-content: center;
       overflow: hidden;
    }

    .slider{
         --items-per-screen: 4;
         --slider-index: 0;
         display: flex;
         flex-grow: 1;
         margin: 0 var(--img-gap);
         transform: translateX(calc(var(--slider-index) * -100%));
         transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out;
    }

    .slider > img {
         flex: 0 0 calc(100% /  var(--items-per-screen));
         max-width: calc(100% / var(--items-per-screen));
         aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
         padding: var(--img-gap);
         border-radius: 1rem;
     }
```

```html
 <div class = "container">
    <button class = "handle left-handle">
        <div class="text">&#8249;</div>
    </button>
    <div class = "slider">

        <img src="Icons/schitts.jpg" stlye="container" alt = "Schitts Creek">
        

        <img src="Icons/familyguy.jpg" alt = "Family Guy">
        <img src="Icons/gameofthrones.jpg" alt = "Game Of Thrones">
        <img src="Icons/sopranos.jpg" alt = "The Sopranos">
        <img src="Icons/southpark.jpg" alt = "South Park">
        <img src="Icons/prisonbreak.jpg" alt = "Prison Break">
        <img src="Icons/curbyourenthusiasm.jpg" alt = "Curb Your Enthusiasm">
        <img src="Icons/americandad.jpg" alt = "American Dad">
        <img src="Icons/sinister.jpg" alt = "Sinister">
        <img src="Icons/superbad.jpg" alt = "Superbad">
        <img src="Icons/hangover.jpg" alt = "The Hangover">
        <img src="Icons/midsommar.jpg" alt = "Midsommar">
    </div>
    <button class = "handle right-handle">
        <div class="text">&#8250;</div>
    </button>
  </div>
```

[Without Anchor element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9MkN.png)

[With Anchor element around first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXQag.png)

```html
<div class = "container">
    <button class = "handle left-handle">
        <div class="text">&#8249;</div>
    </button>
    <div class = "slider">
        <a href="https://www.netflix.com/ca/title/80036165">
        <img src="Icons/schitts.jpg" stlye="container" alt = "Schitts Creek">
        </a>
        <img src="Icons/familyguy.jpg" alt = "Family Guy">
        <img src="Icons/gameofthrones.jpg" alt = "Game Of Thrones">
        <img src="Icons/sopranos.jpg" alt = "The Sopranos">
        <img src="Icons/southpark.jpg" alt = "South Park">
        <img src="Icons/prisonbreak.jpg" alt = "Prison Break">
        <img src="Icons/curbyourenthusiasm.jpg" alt = "Curb Your Enthusiasm">
        <img src="Icons/americandad.jpg" alt = "American Dad">
        <img src="Icons/sinister.jpg" alt = "Sinister">
        <img src="Icons/superbad.jpg" alt = "Superbad">
        <img src="Icons/hangover.jpg" alt = "The Hangover">
        <img src="Icons/midsommar.jpg" alt = "Midsommar">
    </div>
    <button class = "handle right-handle">
        <div class="text">&#8250;</div>
    </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: _Element_, not tag. Please revise your post and put your HTML and CSS in a snippet demo using the editor, _with_ the problem anchor element shown.

Comment: in the html first image with style attribute tell me what does container mean? it is not the property if it is your property then where is the value of the container property. kindly tell more detail about it to get good answer

Comment: The container is used for the buttons on both sides but that is not causing the issue.

Comment: The example in the question (1) doesn't contain any anchor elements and (2) doesn't demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I added the anchor elements to demonstrate the change in layout.

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out

```js
function link(Link){
    window.location.href = Link;
}
```

```html
<img src="Icons/schitts.jpg"  onclick="link('https://www.netflix.com/browse')" stlye="container" alt = "Schitts Creek">
```